# Rcpp Armadillo speedup with large sparse matrix multiplications

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, rcpp, matrix-multiplication

A student of mine has noticed some strange behavior with some code we have implemented in Rcpp Armadillo. Specifically, when we use matrix multiplication with large sparse matrices, there appears to be a dimensionality at which the implementation actually runs more quickly, despite larger dimensions of the matrices being multiplied.

**What is the explanation for this?** Can we modify our implementation in order to see the improved speed at lower dimensions?

We wrote a simple example to illustrate this issue.

```
library(MASS)
library(Matrix)
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("MatMultFunc.cpp")
nreps <- 50
p <- 500
nSeq <- seq(80, 300, by = 20)
storeTime <- matrix(0, nreps, length(nSeq))
set.seed(1)

for (replicate in 1:nreps) {
  for (n in nSeq) {
  
    X <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n)
    l <- n*(n-1)/2
    D <- matrix(0, nrow = l, ncol = n)

    counter <- 1
    for (j in 1:(n-1)) {
      for (k in (j+1):n) {
          D[counter, j] <- 1
          D[counter, k] <- -1
          counter <- counter + 1
      }
    }
    
    
    D <- Matrix(D, sparse=TRUE)
    
    Beta <- rep(0, p)
    Beta[sample(1:p, 50)] <- 1
    Beta <- Matrix(Beta, sparse = TRUE)
    
    ptm <- proc.time()
    RcppMatProds <- MatMultFunc(D, X, Beta)
    t0 <- proc.time() - ptm

    storeTime[replicate, which(nSeq == n)] <- t0[3]

    cat("Replicate: ", replicate, "; n = ", n,"\n")

  }
}

plot(nSeq, colMeans(storeTime), type = "l", ylab="Average runtime in seconds", xlab="n")
```

[image: Timing simulation]

The C++ function we are timing is the following:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List MatMultFunc(arma::sp_mat D, arma::mat X, arma::sp_mat BetaSp){

    arma::vec tXB(D * (X * BetaSp));

    for (int m = 0; m < 1000; m++) {

        tXB = D * (X * BetaSp);
    }

     return List::create(Named("tXB") = wrap(tXB));
}
```

Comment: In C++ the default is to copy function arguments by value, unless explicitly indicated otherwise. Your code unnecessarily copies matrices on entry to MatMultFunc. Change the definition of the function to `List MatMultFunc(const arma::sp_mat& D, const arma::mat& X, const arma::sp_mat& BetaSp)`.  The `&` character is crucial here. The `const` declaration may enable further optimizations.

Comment: I will do this and rerun the experiment momentarily. However, I do not think this explains the strange kink in the timing above since this was the same for all dimensions in the experiment.

Comment: I can reproduce the chart and pattern.  I was able to exclude two possibly aspects namely the return object and possibly costly creation, and the passage of arguments to the function.  Neither seems to matter; the calculation dominates.  Now the question is if a) it is the same for a plain Armadillo C++ program (likely) and b) how alternate approaches such as RcppEigen do.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I can chat with my student about (a). We spent some time trying to write in RcppEigen, but our actual program is quite long and tedious -- the RcppArmadillo version is much easier to read/write.